# How to use multiple CHARINDEX function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code that it will extract the string before comma (","):

```
SELECT LTRIM(LEFT(@Adresa, CHARINDEX(',', @Adresa)-1))
```

Sometimes, comma (',') isn't the character I need to look after because it might be missing. Is there any way to adapt this query in order to look after comma and another value if comma is not found? If it is found, to finish the statement and not to look after the next one. Thanks!

**Edit**

Text to be evaluated: My Address, no. 23.

In some cases, the comma is missing by user mistake and the above code is giving me an error. If the comma is missing, I would like to go next and try to find "no.".

Comment: Some example of inputs and intended outputs would make this much easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Adresa VARCHAR(50) ='My Address, no. 23',
@org_len INT,
@check_len INT,
@Adresa_OUTPUT VARCHAR(50)

SET @org_len = (SELECT LEN(@Adresa))
SET @check_len = (SELECT LEN(SUBSTRING(@Adresa, CHARINDEX(',', @Adresa) + 1, LEN(@Adresa))))

IF @org_len <> @check_len
BEGIN
    SET @Adresa_OUTPUT =(SELECT SUBSTRING(@Adresa,0,CHARINDEX(',',@Adresa,0)))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Adresa_OUTPUT = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@Adresa,0,CHARINDEX('.',@Adresa,0)))
    SET @Adresa_OUTPUT = ( SELECT REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE (@Adresa_OUTPUT), len(@Adresa_OUTPUT) - NULLIF(charindex(' ', REVERSE(@Adresa_OUTPUT)),0))))
END
SELECT @Adresa_OUTPUT
```

Comment: I need the whole string before "," and/or "no.".

Comment: `My Address, no. 23` should return `My Address no 23` or `My Address 23`?

Comment: Just `My Address`.

Comment: `My Address no. 23` what should return ? @srkkk

Comment: `My address` as well. This is what I'm dealing with. If the comma isn't in the string before `no.`, therefore cannot be evaluated, to go next and find where `no.` is starting and then to extract the whole string before `no.`.

Comment: Changed, try now :) @srkkk

Answer (score 2):

This isn't particularly elegant, but a CASE statement will let you try as many options as you care to. Just keep adding WHENs. The first one to hit will return your results.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Adresa VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @t
  (
    Adresa
  )
VALUES
  ('My Address, no. 23'), --With comma
  ('My Address2 no. 23'); --No comma

SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Adresa) > 0
      THEN LTRIM(LEFT(Adresa, CHARINDEX(',', Adresa)-1))
    WHEN CHARINDEX('no.', Adresa) >0
      THEN LTRIM(LEFT(Adresa, CHARINDEX('no.', Adresa)-1))
    ELSE Adresa
  END AS TestString
FROM @t

Results:
+--------------+
|  TestString  |
+--------------+
| My Address   |
| My Address2  |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to return all chars before `no.` , then remove `,` if exists
use the next query:-

```
select Replace((left(@Adresa, charindex('no.', @Adresa) - 2)),',','')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: it will work only for one case, 
your address always ends with `no.`?

Comment: @KillerQueen plz give me one case that not working with this fix.

Comment: `DECLARE @Adresa VARCHAR(50) ='My Address, exampleno. 23.'
Select Replace((left(@Adresa, charindex('no.', @Adresa) - 2)),',','')`

Comment: Is this case a valid case for the OP ?

Comment: Well, it might.